# How do I convert a list into a matrix in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have a list of the form:

```
1 2 3 4
```

I'd like to convert it into a square matrix:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Which I think would be:

```
(1 2;3 4)
```

What's the canonical way to do this for, for `n` sized matrices in KDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
n cut list
```

e.g.

```
q)3 cut til prd 3 3
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Edit:
To insert any list into the closest `n*n` matrix and fill proceeding positions with NA's you can do:

```
q)f:{a:(ceiling sqrt b:count x); a cut x,((a*a) - b)#0N}
q)/e.g.
q)f til 10
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9

q)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `take`

```
q)n: 2
q)(n; n) # 1 2 3 4
1 2
3 4
```

or for an m x n matrix:

```
q)m: 2
q)n: 3
q)(m; n) # 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3
4 5 6
```